# Quick ask : function that prints array of cells - should it be inside my cell class definition?

Tags: java, api, class, design-patterns

```
public class cell{
    String name ;
    float value ;

    public cell(){.....}
    public float getValue(){......}
    public String getName(){........}

    public void printCell(){
         // print name/value bla bla.....
    }

}


public class Cell_test{
public void print_array_cells(cell[][]toprint){
           for(int i = 0 ; i < toprint.length; i++){
                    printcell(toprint) // just code
                }
 }
public static void main....{
         cell monkey_dna = new cell() ;
         cell man_dna = new cell() ;
         cell hen_dna = new cell() ;

         cell []humanoids = {monkey_dna,man_dna, hen_dna} ;
         print_array_cells(humanoids) ;                             
   }
}
```

**i want to have a function that does printing of array of cells.**

Question:

- should i put it into class cell def-n?
- can i put it there?  or must it be inside my test class?

if yes, what if i need it outside of test class?

logically, it is better to have all functions who deal with cell data be made / defined inside cell class?

Comment: classes are  Uppercase!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creat a CellManagement class which contains your print function and the array and functions like `addCell()`, `removeCell()`. In your test class you can creat a instance of your CellManagement and you didnt need any instance of a cell there. So your Cell is the DataAccess Layer, your CellManagement is the Buisiness Layer and the class where you get an instance of CellManagement is your Controller. You should only have one instance of CellManagement, but if you need a function of this class anywhere else you can creat another instance.

Example:

```
public class Cell{
    private String name ;
    private float value ;

    public Cell(){.....}
    public float getValue(){......}
    public String getName(){........}

    //if possible only getters and setter here
    }
}


public class CellManagement{

    //hold the array here and access it via getter
    private Cell[] humanoids;

    public CellManagement() {
        Cell monkey_dna = new Cell();
        Cell man_dna = new Cell();
        Cell hen_dna = new Cell();
        humanoids = {monkey_dna,man_dna, hen_dna}
    }

    public void print_array_cells(){
        for(int i = 0 ; i < humanoids.length; i++){
            printcell(humanoids) // just code
        }
    }

    //add and remove functions..

}

public static void main....{

        CellManagement cm = new CellManagement();
        cm.print_array_cells() ;                             
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> logically, it is better to have all functions who deal with cell data
>   be made / defined inside cell class?

Generally, yes. You don't want to expose the members of a class, even via getters etc. If you do, do it in a fashion that allows you to change the implementation without having to change the API.

For your particular question, I would add the method to render your `cell` class *within* the class. However I would perhaps write it to take an `OutputStream` or `Writer` such that it can write to a generic destination, rather than specifically to `stdout` or `stderr`.

e.g.

```
cell.outputTo(outputstream);
```

I would then follow this pattern through to your `Cell` array. I would perhaps have a class representing this `Cell` array (call it a `Culture`, perhaps?) and that would be responsible for maintaining the underlying array (or whatever you choose your underlying collection to be implemented as), asserting the structure, contents etc. Otherwise you'll have a collection within your solution that can't assert such things centrally.

Comment: what? no getters? its a recommendation to MAKE object fields accessible ONLY through known places like getters!

Comment: I'd recommend not using getters if at all possible, and make your object act upon its members itself, rather than expose attributes for you to work on outside the class. Look up the Rule of Demeter for more info

Comment: so rendering cell class means using some standard output? is this a good practice?

Comment: wow, this answer is really mind blowing to me! I did not even think of creating another class Culture who WILL ASSUME he has ARRAY of cells!thx

Answer (score 1):

Usually you put methods dealing with an object's internal state inside its class definition.

If you have a utility method for dealing with related stuff and you don't know where to put it, you can make it a static method inside the class.

Comment: what? no getters? its a recommendation to MAKE object fields accessible ONLY through known places like getters!

Comment: sorry, i put my question in the wrong thread, thx, and ignore this!

Answer (score 0):

You should make service class and put all the functions that perform some task or calculation... cell class should only contain getter and setter method only

Comment: The cell class should contain all its functionality, or a large part thereof. Otherwise it's merely a structure

Comment: apparently, this is about design of classes question: some recommend to NOT USE getters, some recommend them , but only inside the class and use SERVICE CLASS! - never heard of service classes - but it sounds good

Answer (score 0):

> logically, it is better to have all functions who deal with cell data be made / defined inside cell class?

Sometimes, but sometimes it's better to split data and logic. For example, in java we don't have **Integer#print(PrintWriter p)** or even **Integer#max(Integer otherInt)**. When you split your class to Data and Logic/Functions you can add new logic/functions without changing the existing classes, you really just "add" new code.

There is a nice way to separate Data from Functions - the Visitor pattern. The following is an example for your case:

1. define a class Row which contains array of Cell
2. define CellVisitor interface
3. define RowVisitor interface, which extends CellVisitor
4. implement RowVisitor by RowPrinter class

   ```
   public interface CellVisitor {

       void onCell(Cell cell);
   }

   public interface RowVisitor extends CellVisitor {

       void onRowStarted(Row row);

       void onRowFinished(Row row);
   }

   public class Cell {

       private String name;
       private float value;

       public void visit(CellVisitor visitor) {
           visitor.onCell(this);
       }

       public String getName() {
           return name;
       }

       public float getValue() {
           return value;
       }
   }

   public class Row {

       private Cell[] cells;

       public void visit(RowVisitor visitor) {
           visitor.onRowStarted(this);

           for (Cell c : cells) {
               c.visit(visitor);
           }

           visitor.onRowFinished(this);
       }
   }
   ```

And now the printer:

```
    public class RowPrinter implements RowVisitor {

        private final StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
        private int cellCnt;

        @Override
        public void onRowStarted(Row row) {
            cellCnt = 0;
            text.setLength(0);
            text.append('[');
        }

        @Override
        public void onCell(Cell cell) {
            if (cellCnt > 0) {
                text.append(',');
            }
            text.append(cell.getName())
                    .append(':')
                    .append(cell.getValue());
            cellCnt++;
        }

        @Override
        public void onRowFinished(Row row) {
            text.append(']');
            System.out.println(text.toString());
        }
    }
```

Or any other useful visitor/function (CSV printer to file, sum of values, total count of cells, etc.)

```
    Row row = ...
    row.visit(new RowPrinter()); // print the row
```

Also, note, even if you distribute such API in binaries, any client will be able to add his own function in very gracefully way.